# Grails Markdown library needed to release after Jsoup renamed the Whitelist class to Safelist in v1.15.1

Tags: grails

The last and only version of Grails Markdown library v3.0.0 was released way back in 2015. Internally Grails Markdown used Jsoup where there is a class rename that has happed for v1.15.1.
Available in [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/eabfcdd25d3d1604baaa78d585ea671540a45adf/CHANGES#L313)

> Improvement: renamed the Whitelist class to Safelist, with the goal of
> more inclusive language. A shim is provided
> for backward compatibility (source and binary). This shim is marked as deprecated and will be removed in the
> jsoup 1.15.1 release.
> https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/1464

So for CVE fixing in Jsoup if I upgrade to v1.15.3, then the code is breaking because the grails markdown library still refers to that class as Whitelist. There is a need for a release from the Grails team side.

If anyone is having any workaround please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grails-markdown plugin is not a Grails team plugin, but rather a 3rd-party plugin, and according to its page on plugins.grails.org, appears to have been abandoned for some time. The linked source code repository does not appear to be available.

I managed to find an archive of the source code and put it up onto GitHub here: https://github.com/mattmoss/grails-markdown . I have not checked in any way the content of the plugin, whether it works or not, nor for any security issues, etc. At this time, I am not planning on making fixes, adding new features, or publishing it in any way. But the source code is there should you need it.